# Update data between two Activities Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am making a simple Android game that displaying a sequence of visual stimuli. I have two activities (Main & Settings). In the setting you will be able to edit the number of stimuli. When I edit the number it does not update at the main activity.

This is into Main activity onCreate

```
settings = new SettingsActivity();
setNrOfStimuli = settings.getSetNrOfStimuli();
stimuli = new int[setNrOfStimuli];
```

This is on Main activity

```
public void onSettingBtnClicked(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class));
}
```

This is on Settings activity

```
public void onBackBtnClicked(View view) {
    setNrOfStimuli = Integer.parseInt(inputNrOfStimuliView.getText().toString());
    finish();
}
```

I can transfer the value of number by Intent or getter & setter but the problem is with initialization when it comes back to Main activity from Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `SharedPreferences`  to store user's settings. You can go through this tutorial to learn about it.
https://www.javatpoint.com/android-preferences-example

You have to change this in the tutorial's code:
In **prefs.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- you do not worry about how this information will be stored, it will be handled 
by  the android. You have to use those data by getting that data by their key -->
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="stimuli_numbers"
            android:summary="Please enter Number of stimuli"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:title="Number of stimuli" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

and in your **Main Activity**

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);

//get the number of stimuli
//stimuli_numbers is the key and 0 is the default value (you can change this according to yours.
setNrOfStimuli = Integer.valueOf(prefs.getString("stimuli_numbers","0");
```